# flutter Project is not working in simulator mac os

Tags: flutter, dart, simulator

I installed the flutter and using android studio to run the flutter project on simulator. I clone the project from git and run it shows this error

```
 Error: To set up CocoaPods for ARM macOS, run:
  arch -x86_64 sudo gem install ffi

Error running pod install
Error launching application on iPhone 14 Pro Max.
```

but when I make the new basic project it runs fine but not the cloned project. I tried some stuff.

```
open ~/.profile and add these 
exports export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
export LANGUAGE=en_US.UTF-8
export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
```

Also uninstall cocoapods and reinstall again. but nothing works for me.
what i am missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Spending few hours on this problem finally it works for me.

**Step 1:** Uninstall the cocoapods by running this command in your project folder terminal

```
sudo gem uninstall cocoapods
```

**Step 2:** Install the cocoapods by running this command

```
brew install cocoapods
```

**Note:** Not forget to restart the android studio otherwise it would show another error. just close your project, close android studio, rerun the project or simulator.
Hope it will help someone.